# My users are paying and sometimes not getting the product they pay for. How can I solve this?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, web-applications, stripe-payments

I have a job site where people can post jobs with or without being logged in: www.jobdirecto.com

I implemented Stripe Checkout a while ago. Mostly it works well, but every once in a while, a user pays and he doesn't get the product.

Then I have no way of knowing, programmatically, (1) if someone paid for the product, (2) which product they paid for and (3) what was the information they wanted to post in the site.

I usually end up finding out about it by chance (because I check my Stripe acc or the angry user sent me an email).

The flow of how things work now:
1. User (authenticated or not) fills out the form and when he submits, his post info goes into a **cookie**.
2. He gets redirected to a page where he can decide to either pay or back out.
3. If he clicks pay, he gets redirected to the Stripe page.
4. If the payment is successful, he gets redirected to the confirm page.
5. In the confirm page, he clicks **publish** and his post gets into the database and thus, published.

Clearly, if something fails in between 4. and 5., his information will be lost.

Should I change this flow and put the info in the database before he pays? Should I modify the Stripe code somehow?

Thanks for your help.

```
function StripeButton() {
  const context = useContext(LanguageContext);
  const stripe = Stripe("pk_live_5PjwBk9dSdW7htTKHQ3HKrTd");

  const [error, setError] = useState();

  const handleClick = () => {
      console.log("I'm in stripe look");
    stripe
      .redirectToCheckout({
        items: [{ sku: "sku_FAe7tbPK29byHW", quantity: 1 }],
        successUrl:
          window.location.protocol + "//www.jobdirecto.com/jobConfirm",
        cancelUrl:
          window.location.protocol + "//www.jobdirecto.com/StripeButton"
      })
      .then(result => {
        if (result.error) {
          setError(result.error.message);
        }
      });

    event.preventDefault();
    axios.post("/wantsToPay").then(resp => {
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
          className="buttonBasic" onClick={handleClick}>
        {context.jobPayPage.buttonYES}
        <br />
      </button>
      <div>{error}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default StripeButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

So coming at this from a logic perspective, you hit the nail on the head with where the problem lies. You're currently depending on the customer to take an extra step that they may or may not realize they need to do. In most (read almost all) cases, the customer is going to expect that once money has changed hands, they're done. They expect that the store they just sent money to is going to know what it is they just purchased.

Here is my suggestion to shore this up. When the customer clicks the button to "checkout", immediately store his "cart" on your server using whatever unique methods you have at your disposal. Since they can be unauthenticated, then I would suggest creating a session ID, if one does not already exist. Client side, this can be stored in a cookie. So that if they back out or accidentally close the browser, they can come back and their cart still exists (you may already have something like this implemented). When storing the information on your server, I would suggest specifically marking it as a pending transaction so that you can clearly see these in your database.

With the above solution in place, I would then rewrite your code surrounding steps 4 and 5 so that when the customer hits the "pay" button, he never sees the "confirm page". Rather, the confirm URL is simply javascript logic (client or server) to rewrite the PENDING state to CONFIRMED in your database so that you can send your customer his product.